# Moving MSDB database files fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, msdb

I'm trying to relocate system databases files.
I managed to do that with the tempdb database, but I'm stuck with msdb.

When I run:

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id IN DB_ID('msdb')
```

it shows that the logical names are  'MSDBData' and 'MSDBLog'. Then when I run below mention TSQL query

```
alter database tempdb modify file (name = MSDBData, filename = 'C:\Data\MSDBData.mdf')
```

I am getting the following error: `MODIFY FILE failed. File 'MSDBData' does not exist.`

MS Sql 2008 R2 server version: 10.50.1600

Comment: alter database tempdb or msdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use:

```
... WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) IN ('msdb', 'xxx', ...)
```

or

```
... WHERE database_id = DB_ID('msdb')
```

Syntax for `ALTER DATABASE` is:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_name , FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name' )
```

In your case values are as follow:

- database_name = MSDB
- logical_name = MSDBData (or MSDBLog)
- 'new_path\os_file_name' = 'C:\Data\MSDBData.mdf'

Then you can follow this procedure for MSDB:

- execute `ALTER DATABASE MSDB MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBData, FILENAME = '...new path' )`
- and/or execute `ALTER DATABASE MSDB MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBLog, FILENAME = '...new path' )`
- stop SQL Server service
- Move MSDBData and/or MSDBLog to their new location
- Start SQL Server service
- Check new file location

  ```
  SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location
  FROM sys.master_files
  WHERE database_id = DB_ID('msdb')
  ```

You must replace value such as MSDB, file location, file name with the correct values for your environment.